# How to retrieve object from MongoDB collection in PHP ?

Tags: php, mongodb

My PHP code is something like this ...

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';  
    $dbname = 'test_pranav';  
    $connection = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");
    $connection->selectDB('test_pranav');
    $collection = $connection->selectCollection('test_pranav', 'posts');
    $testResult = $collection->find();  
    print_r($testResult);
    exit;
?>
```

I inserted record manully through PhpMongo UI tool. But when I try to print the contents for  same table it gives empty object.

Please let me know where am I wrong ?

Comment: Did you finally succeeded ?

Answer (score 0):

`$collection->find()` return a `MongoCursor` object which is an iterator. The easiest way to retrieve the results is then :

```
$cursor = $collection->find();  
print_r(iterator_to_array($cursor));
```

Complete documentation for MongoDB PHP driver can be found here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php

Answer (score 0):

This is why:

```
$connection->selectDB('test_pranav');
$collection = $connection->selectCollection('test_pranav', 'posts');
```

`selectDB` returns a MongoDB instance so you need:

```
$db = $connection->selectDB('test_pranav');
print_r($db->test_pranav->find());
```

which should then print out a `MongoCursor` object and as @Guillaume says you then use `iterator_to_array()` on that.